# Send a Receipt to a user when adding a manual membership OR any payment

Tags: receipts

Using WP4.3.1 and CiviCRM 4.6.9
When creating a manual (off line) membership or payment for a contact is there a way to have a receipt of that sent to another user(email address)?  And is there a way to modify what is on that receipt?

Comment: Could this be done using CiviRules?

Comment: I'd like to tag onto this question that I recently migrated from Joomla to Wordpress (also upgraded from 4.2.7 to 4.4.6). And in Joomla when you ran an offline contribution (and selected a contribution page) the email receipt was cc'd according to how the contribution page was set up. Now in my Wordpress version that does not happen. Not sure if this is an upgrade issue or a CMS issue. But to answer part of Gary's question, there is a Message Template in System Workflow Messages for Offline Contributions and offline event registrations.

Comment: I saw/see that but how would I add a CC to this email?  We need a copy not only to go to the contact but to another internal staff member.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, it used to CC based on the settings of the contribution page but no longer. I'd test this on the demo site(s) but I don't think those allow for emails to be sent out - so I wouldn't have much to report. I think this may be an issue to be reported as a bug but can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to hook something together using CiviRules, but it's unlikely - because CiviRules won't have the same context for generating the receipt.  So CiviRules is probably fine for sending an internal email stating, "Hey, this contribution came in, here are the details", but (most likely) can't generate the exact receipt.

That's probably good enough - but if it's not, you can create an extension to handle this, using [hook_civicrm_alterMailParams](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams).